# Ubuntu 14.04 SSH from Third Party, No Error Cause

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, connection, keys

I have two instances of Ubuntu 14.04 running. I am utilizing a third party service that accesses the instance(s) via ssh using its own generated key pair, of which it provides me the public key.

I take the following steps to allow access.

```
sudo adduser rjmetric
sudo mkdir /home/rjmetric/.ssh
sudo nano /home/rjmetric/.ssh/authorized_keys <<PASTE PUBLIC KEY>>
sudo chown -R rjmetric:rjmetric /home/rjmetric
sudo chmod -R 700 /home/rjmetric/.ssh
```

The first instance i have up and connected and do not recall doing anything else other than the stated commands above.

A second instance, created recently, does not connect and gives the error

```
Connection closed by 54.88.76.97 [preauth]
```

I have not changed the sshd_config for either instance other than to set the log level to DEBUG3.

I have verified that the firewall access rules are exactly the same for both instances. This is what the directories look like in the failing instance.

**/home**

[image]

**/home/rjmetric**
[image]

**/home/rjmetric/.ssh**
[image]

This is the output of /var/log/auth.log when it tries to connect.

```
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[789]: debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[789]: debug1: Forked child 1042.
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[789]: debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 737
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[789]: debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[789]: debug3: send_rexec_state: done
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug3: oom_adjust_restore
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj to 0
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe 7 sock 8
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: Connection from 54.88.76.97 port 55652 on 10.10.1.69 port 22
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: Network child is on pid 1043
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug3: preauth child monitor started
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug3: privsep user:group 104:65534 [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug1: permanently_set_uid: 104/65534 [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[986]: debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request winadj@putty.projects.tartarus.org reply 1
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[986]: debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[986]: debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req winadj@putty.projects.tartarus.org
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[986]: debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 8372
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0  [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96 [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:  [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0  [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0  [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug3: mm_key_sign entering [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 6 [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 6
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug3: mm_answer_sign
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug3: mm_answer_sign: signature 0x7f583d450730(99)
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 7
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: monitor_read: 6 used once, disabling now
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug3: mm_key_sign: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_SIGN [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 7 [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: kex_derive_keys [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1 [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[986]: debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request winadj@putty.projects.tartarus.org reply 1
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[986]: debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[986]: debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req winadj@putty.projects.tartarus.org
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[986]: debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 8216
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: Connection closed by 54.88.76.97 [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug1: do_cleanup [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering [preauth]
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug1: do_cleanup
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_cleanup entering
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug1: Killing privsep child 1043
Mar  7 21:18:07 ubuntu sshd[1042]: debug1: audit_event: unhandled event 12
```

I do not see anything being logged that would indicate a problem or what is occurring that would cause the connection to close.

I have also verified that I can connect from my PC using Putty and my own generated public/private key with the same user.

I would be highly appreciative if someone could point me in the right direction to get this damn thing to connect.

Comment: The most productive way forward is probably to run the SSH client in verbose mode since it looks like the client is closing the connection. If that's not possible turn on debug on the working server and compare the log entries with the non-working server.

Comment: `ssh -vvv server` verbose mode from client will give you some more clue.

Comment: It looks like an issue with the key itself or with the other side.